# Is there a way to report/print out results during fitting/predicting phases in whatever models used in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

The usual way we do in scikit-learn is as follows:

- define a model
- model.fit
- model.predict

Then we get the prediction result all at once. Is there a way that we can print out the values of parameters during fitting phase as well as prediction values during predicting phase?

For example with the linear model: b0 + b1x = y. The parameters b0 and b1 get updated every epoch. I want to print out the values of them in each iteration.

Comment: What values do you mean?

Comment: for example with the linear model: b0 + b1x = y. The parameters b0 and b1 get updated every epoch. I want to print out the values of them in each iteration.

Comment: What does `verbose` do?

Comment: I dont know. Could you give me more explanation on that?